# How to sort specific Hierarchy Level in OLAP (SSAS) via MDX

Tags: sorting, ssas, mdx, hierarchy, olap

I'm using **SSAS OLAP** and I want to apply sorting of the levels of a hierarchy.

I know that I can sort the whole hierarchy via ORDER function (I have some issues when I'm trying to apply **DESC** sorting on the whole hierarchy), but what I really want to achieve is sorting of a specific level. For example in the [Date].[Calendar] hierarchy (Adventure Works Cube), I want to have **ASC** sorting of years, **DESC** sorting of Quarter, **ASC** sorting of Months, etc.
I do not want to break the hierarchy (using BASC or BDESC), I just need them sorted on the same level. Do you have an idea if this is possible at all, as I was unable to find anything simillar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it is impossible to achieve the desired effect - there's no such MDX query that can sort different levels with different sorting type. More information is available in [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bd7b7957-e1e1-4fd8-8d3d-be2186e52d3a/how-to-apply-sorting-for-each-level-of-a-hierarchy?forum=sqlanalysisservices).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is crossjoining the ordered correspoding attribute hierarchies.  Could you verify the results of the following:

```
select
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] on 0,

Order(
[Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS,
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
,ASC)
*
Order(
[Date].[Calendar Quarter of Year].[Calendar Quarter of Year].MEMBERS,
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
,DESC)
*
Order(
[Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS,
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
,ASC)

ON 1
from [Adventure Works]
```

Including the all members could help ([Date].[Calendar Year] instead of [Date].[Calendar Year] in case of the first crossjoin set)

Philip,

Comment: Thank you for your answer Philip! Unfortunately this is not working - maybe I was not clear enough - my idea is to sort the levels based on their key, not by the measure. For example if we have the following structure:
-2009
 -Q1
  -Jan
  -Feb
 -Q2
  -May
  -June
-2010
 -Q1
  -Jan
  -Feb
 -Q2
  -May
  -June

I would like to be able to sort the data in the following order (DESC for years, ASC for Quarters, DESC for months):
-2010
 -Q1
  -Feb
  -Jan
 -Q2
  -June
  -May
-2009
 -Q1
  -Feb
  -Jan
 -Q2
  -June
  -May

Answer (score 0):

The following is a working solution, if not a really nice one:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[year] as
            [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Properties('Key0', typed)
     MEMBER Measures.[qtr or mth] as
            [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Properties('Key1', typed)
     MEMBER Measures.[sortKey] as
            CASE
                WHEN [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Level IS [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year] THEN
                     Measures.[year] * 1000
                WHEN [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Level IS [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Quarter] THEN
                     Measures.[year] * 1000 + (5 - Measures.[qtr or mth]) * 100
                ELSE // month
                     Measures.[year] * 1000 + (4 -  Int((Measures.[qtr or mth] - 1) / 3)) * 100 + Measures.[qtr or mth]
            END
SELECT {Measures.[year], Measures.[qtr or mth], Measures.[sortKey]}
       ON COLUMNS,
       Order(
               [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year]
               +
               [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Quarter]
               +
               [Date].[Calendar].[Month]
               ,
               Measures.[sortKey]
               ,BASC
       )
       ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

The measures on the columns are just for clarification how it works. And the main logic is in the generation of the `sortKey` measure which generates an integer key as follows: four digits for the year, one digit for the backwards quarter (Q4 -> 1, ... Q1 -> 4), two digits for the month. Then, using that, it is straightforward to call `Order` to return the sorted set.